# How can i determine which packages from 'npm ls --all' are devDependencies

Tags: javascript, npm

I am scanning all the npm packages of multiple repositories, i do this using npm ls --all --json and then i traverse the dependency tree, storing each package in a database.

However, i would like add a flag to each package in a specific repository, which indicates whether or not that package is a dev dependency in the given repository.

I can see that the information is available in package-lock.json and also somewhat in package.json, however it does not seem to be included in the json structure i get from npm ls (unless i am missing something)

One solution i considered, is taking the name of each package, and looking it up in package.json to determine whether it resides under dependencies{} or devdependencies{}. But this seems a bit hacky and i was wondering if there's a better solution?

Comment: Something like `npm ls --all --include=dev --omit=prod`? You could've tried finding it out for yourself @ https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-ls

Comment: Thank you for the response. I should have mentioned that i tried that already but i seem to be getting both dev and prod dependencies if i do `npm ls --all --include=dev --omit=prod --json`

Comment: You're right. Tried some other commands/combinations, it doesn't seem possible (maybe programmatically exploring package.json and pick out the dev_dependencies entries to create a custom `npm ls [package-spec]` query string).

Comment: `npm ls --all --omit=dev` seems to give only non-development dependencies. You can run this and `npm ls --all` and diff the results to find the development dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, that is what i ended up doing, i appreciate the help